# Why do asynchronous tasks (functions) not run unless awaited?

Tags: rust

In Rust I have found that an asynchronous task or function (let's even say a future) is not invoked in the runtime unless it is awaited. In other languages such as C# or NodeJS it is possible to define `async` tasks and run them concurrently as an `async` task is meant to provide non-blocking IO. For instance:

```
public Task Run();
public Task ListenToMusic();

public async Task RunAndListenToMusic() {
   Task run = Run(); // the task is already running
   Task listenToMusic = ListenToMusic(); // the task is already running
   await Task.WhenAll(run, listenToMusic); 
}
```

I have tested this mechanism in Rust using a `for` loop that actually prints out sequential numbers and found that, they are always executed in order, meaning that the second task is run after the first one.

For people like me who are from the world of dotnet or Java, this is a weird behavior. What is actually going on, I searched but I need someone to explain this in a little bit more details and more simply.

Comment: cause future are lazy in rust you may be interested in [`spawn()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.14.0/tokio/fn.spawn.html)

Comment: @Stargateur Is there a way to start a future without awaiting it?

Comment: @Stargateur: Great! but this is not what `async` is meant to be, is it? Laziness is one concept, asynchrony is another.

Comment: https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/spawning

Comment: Because if not it would not be a zero cost abstraction.

Comment: @Stargateur: Threading is different from asynchrony!

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: So where is the non-blocking IO advantage? It keeps running one task and puts the other one on hold. Don't you think that is actually a blocking behavior?

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder I suggest you read my link and not just the tittle. Rust is a hard language, Async Rust is harder. I do not advice people to start learning rust with async.

Comment: No, because you don't always use `await`: you `select!` futures, for example, which compile down to polling both of them at the same time. In fact, in _any_ language `await` is "blocking" this way, and you use combinators like `Promise.all()` in js to run many in parallel. The only difference is that if you want fire-and-forget, you need to `spawn()` in Rust while other languages do that automatically. It will not be more costly in Rust, just less costly in the times you don't need spawning.

Comment: @Stargateur: I am already familiar with Tokio library. The problem is that Tokio is not included in the standard library of rust. Furthermore, spawning a thread is good for a CPU bound operation, while asynchronous tasks that run on the same thread are IO or memory bound.

Comment: If you know about the event loop in js, tokio does the same for spawned tasks.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: Ok, one question, the spawned tasks in tokio, do they run on the same or the main thread?

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder This is not true. For CPU-bound tasks, you need to use `spawn_blocking()`. `spawn()` is exactly the equivalent of `new Promise(...)`/`Task.Run(...)`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: I asked that question because JS is single threaded as you know.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: Exactly, `async` is not meant to be CPU bound, that actually needs multi-threading. This is what is confusing me

Comment: Whatever the runtime decides. tokio switches between threads as appropriate (if not instructed to use the single-thread flavor).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: Yes that is right, but my problem is, why do I need a separate thread at all for an async Task?

Comment: You get a benefit over js: you can use multicores better. This is not something you should worry about, tokio does that for you.

Comment: **`spawn()` does not create a new OS thread.**

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: It is a philosophical question, why would rust mix threading and asynchrony at all?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: Thank you for helping me understand this behavior. What if I do not want to use Tokio and want to rely on the rust's standard library?

Comment: Because OS threads are heavyweight but can use multiple cores. But this is really not a question for SO, I think.

Comment: Rust's std does not contain an async executor, and won't have in the near future, at least. Perhaps you can do with the `futures` crate, but I won't recommend it (and you won't have async IO either).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240156/discussion-between-chayim-friedman-and-arnold-zahrneinder).

Comment: Rust combines threading and async because that is the only way to make use of multiple cores. While a single code is sufficient for everything to work due to async semantics, multiple cores give your server better response times. This is not unique to Rust, C# and Kotlin happily run async code on multiple OS threads. In tokio you can request a single-threaded executor, and then you'll get single-threaded execution like you're used to from JavaScript. (You'll still need to call `spawn()` to run futures in the "background", but that's ok because `spawn()` spawns a task, not a thread.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some Rust code that is equivalent to your example:

```
use tokio; // 1.14.0

async fn task1() {
    for i in 0..10 {
        println!("Task 1: {}", i);
    }
}

async fn task2() {
    for i in 0..10 {
        println!("Task 2: {}", i);
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let t1 = task1();
    let t2 = task2();
    tokio::join!(t1, t2);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8142a2b96149d1e1e06bccbf7bd6dcb9)

If you run this code, you will notice that it executes all of `task1` before executing `task2`. This is expected because execution is single-threaded, so `task1` will run so long as it doesn't attempt a blocking operation. However if we add blocking operations (here I've used `sleep`, but the same goes for I/O operations):

```
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio; // 1.14.0

async fn task1() {
    for i in 0..10 {
        println!("Task 1: {}", i);
        tokio::time::sleep (Duration::from_millis (1)).await;
    }
}

async fn task2() {
    for i in 0..10 {
        println!("Task 2: {}", i);
        tokio::time::sleep (Duration::from_millis (1)).await;
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let t1 = task1();
    let t2 = task2();
    tokio::join!(t1, t2);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ce58aa406ca92250331f23a6cd5aa4a6)

Now we see that operations are interleaved: when a task blocks the other tasks get a chance to run, which is the whole point of async programming.

Comment: Great answer, but what happens if you don't use tokio and rely on what comes in the standard library? The second example as I have tested (without tokio) does not work as expected.

Comment: In order to run async tasks, you need an executor. The standard library does not provide one since there is no "one true way" to make one, so you will need to either roll your own or use an existing one like `tokio` or [`async-std`](https://crates.io/crates/async-std) or one of [these](https://crates.io/search?page=1&per_page=10&q=executor). How tasks are scheduled depends on your executor.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. I understand that since Rust is actually a language which is made to be close to hardware, it is not supposed to provide out of the box features that we have in other languages.